# Where I can change the profile picture in the react-admin header?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I am using social login in react-admin (former admin-on-rest) and I have the user picture from his social media, however I didn't find how to change the user profile image in the top right corner of the screen:

[image: Profile image]

Is there any prop to be set, like custom login or custom logout button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the process involves a lot of code as you'll have to rewrite the `UserMenu` completely. To use it, you'll also have to implement a custom `Layout` with a custom `AppBar`. The process will be simplified when https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2391 will be merged.

```
// in src/MyUserMenu.js
import React, { Children, cloneElement } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import { translate } from 'ra-core';

class UserMenu extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.node,
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        logout: PropTypes.node,
        translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        label: 'ra.auth.user_menu',
    };

    state = {
        auth: true,
        anchorEl: null,
    };

    handleChange = (event, checked) => {
        this.setState({ auth: checked });
    };

    handleMenu = event => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
    };

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
    };

    render() {
        const { children, label, logout, translate } = this.props;
        if (!logout && !children) return null;
        const { anchorEl } = this.state;
        const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

        return (
            <div>
                <Tooltip title={label && translate(label, { _: label })}>
                    <IconButton
                        arial-label={label && translate(label, { _: label })}
                        aria-owns={open ? 'menu-appbar' : null}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={this.handleMenu}
                        color="inherit"
                    >
                        {/* Replace this icon with whatever you want, a user avatar or another icon */}
                        <AccountCircle />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
                <Menu
                    id="menu-appbar"
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'top',
                        horizontal: 'right',
                    }}
                    transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'top',
                        horizontal: 'right',
                    }}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                    {Children.map(children, menuItem =>
                        cloneElement(menuItem, { onClick: this.handleClose })
                    )}
                    {logout}
                </Menu>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default translate(UserMenu);

// in src/MyAppBar.js
import { AppBar } from 'react-admin';
import MyUserMenu from './MyUserMenu';

const MyAppBar = (props) => <AppBar {...props} userMenu={MyUserMenu} />;

// in src/MyLayout.js
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import MyAppBar from './MyAppBar';

const MyLayout = (props) => <Layout {...props} appBar={MyAppBar} />;

export default MyLayout;
```

Documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-appbar